# Single-quoting `${vcs_info_msg_0_}` causes multi-line ZSH prompt to go single-lined

Tags: git, command-prompt, zsh, oh-my-zsh

While trying to customize my ZSH prompt, I went to add `vcs_info`, and my existing multi-line prompt went single lined, and loses the datetime info on the right side of the second line:

```
.-[~/Documents/role-compositional-[master●]>--------------<root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-3gb-nyc3-01] 
`--#>                                                                 <Sat, Dec 21 @ 23:27]
```

to

```
.-[~/Documents/role-compositional-[master●]>--------------<root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-3gb-nyc3-01] `--#>
```

---

I derived what I have from adam2. I went to add `'${vcs_info_msg_0_}'` to my prompt string after the directory location, but single-quoting everything flattened it into one line. Then I went to abstract it. Something like:

```
prompt_1a="%~"
prompt_1b='${vcs_info_msg_0_}'
prompt_1="$prompt_1a$prompt_1b"
```

But that caused the exact same effect. For reference, I'm dealing with the source [here](https://gitlab.com/smacz/dotfiles/blob/master/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/andrewcz.zsh-theme), specifically line 77:

```
prompt_line_1a2="${vcs_info_msg_0_}"
```

As soon as I change the above double quotes to single quotes, the prompt collapses to a single line. However, with the double quotes, I have to source my `~/.zshrc` before the `[master●]` section of the prompt can updated. It does not update without sourcing the `~/.zshrc`.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example here (preferably one that strips out all the colorizing so we can focus on what actually makes a difference)?

Comment: Turns out that the middle spacing was being mis-calculated. Fixed with the latest push to master.